# On NodeMCU or Arduino, what is the best rest state for a GPIO pin?

Tags: arduino, gpio, nodemcu

If a pin is unused, what should be its rest state?

I'm thinking gpio.INPUT makes sense, or maybe gpio.OUT set to gpio.LO, grounding the pin.

Is there a customary or preferred setting for unused pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For unconnected pins `INPUT_PULLUP` or `OUTPUT`. Using Pull-Up is better if there is any possibility that board layout will chance and someone connects this pin to ground/Vcc directly. It's better to sink small current to ground than short output pin to different logic level.
- For connected pins INPUT (connection should be connected to `LOW` or `HIGH` level)